# Expose a content type field in drupal 7

Tags: views

I have created a user field in a content type article.Let say the field name analysis status which is a list selection box.I have made this field as collection in a field name Collection.

Now I created a view and I tried to expose the analysis status field in the filter criteria but the field is not get exposed.

Can anyone help me how to expose a user field(created by me) in view.

I have to filter the content title and the body based on the analysis field value.

The  Analysis status contains the following values.

```
1. New
2. Closed
```

I if select New the view filter has to filter the content based on the NEW value for a particular content type.Same this is followed for the closed also.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. Adding an exposed filter is similar to a normal filter on `Content: My Field (my_field)`, except that you have to check the "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it" checkbox when configuring the filter. If that doesn't answer your question, please improve your question.

Comment: User understanding is correct.If I expose the field by check the "Expose this filter to visitor" it is not getting exposed.I do no why the field is not getting exposed.It is same for all the fields.

Comment: Could you please provide more info about your issue? What you're trying to accomplish is very straightforward. For example here: http://screencast.com/t/Zn4hLxmb my filter settings and they work for me just great.

Comment: That sounds like a bug I haven't seen before. I advise you to backup your site first and then try to track down the error by reverting to the bartik theme and switching off all additional modules one-by-one. Since your situation seems to be specific to your situation only, I'm voting for this question to be closed as "too localized".

Comment: >>> I'm voting for this question to be closed as "too localized" <<<
I support.